# if and else question in r, got a result with number that doesnt exist in options I gave

Tags: r, if-statement

I tried to make this code

```
AndreyIndex=function(y){
if(y == 1982|1983|1997|1998|2015|2016){
  print("very strong El Nino")
} else if(1957|1958|1965|1966|1972|1973|1987|1988|1991|1992){
  print("Strong El Nino")
} else if(1951|1952|1963|1964|1968|1969|1986|1987|1994|1995|2002|2003|2009|2010){
  print("Modereate El Nino")
} else if(1952|1953|1954|1958|1959|1969|1970|1976|1977|1978|1979|1980|2004|2005|2006|2007|2014|2015|2018|2019|2020){
  print("Weak El Nino")
} else if(1973||1974|1975|1976|1988|1989|1998|1999|2000|2007|2008|2010|2011){
  print("Strong La Nina")
}else if(1955|1956|1970|1971|1995|1996|2011|2012|2020|2021){
  print("Moderate La Nina")
}else if(1954|1955|1964|1965|1971|1972|1974|1975|1983|1984|1985|2000|2001|2005|2006|2008|2009|2016|2017|2018){
  print("Weak La Nina")
} else{
  print("No La Nina or El Nino events")
}
}
AndreyIndex(5000)
```

and got the result

```
> AndreyIndex(5000)
[1] "very strong El Nino"
```

but the number 5000 do not exist here at all, what i did wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need to put `y ==` in *each* of those `else if` statements?

Comment: I posted an answer below, but the problem is that `if(y == 1 | 2)` is different from `if(y == 1 | y == 2)`.  `if(y == 1 | 2)` evaluates two separate conditions.  The first is whether or not y is equal to 1.  The second is 2 and as you can see from `as.logical(2)`, it evaluates to `TRUE`.  So, the condition `y==1 | 2` will always be true because 2 always evaluates to `TRUE`, as do all non-zero numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to clean the function up a bit:

```
library(dplyr)
AndreyIndex=function(y){
  case_when(
    y %in% c(1982, 1983, 1997, 1998, 2015, 2016) ~ "very strong El Nino", 
    y %in% c(1957, 1958, 1965, 1966, 1972, 1973, 1987, 
             1988, 1991, 1992) ~ "Strong El Nino", 
    y %in% c(1951,1952,1963,1964,1968,1969,1986,1987,1994,
             1995,2002,2003,2009,2010) ~ "Moderate El Nino",
    y %in% c(1952, 1953, 1954, 1958, 1959, 1969, 1970, 
             1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
             2007, 2014, 2015, 2018, 2019, 2020) ~ "Weak El Nino", 
    y %in% c(1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1988, 1989, 
             1998, 1999, 2000, 2007, 2008, 2010, 2011) ~ "Strong La Nina", 
    y %in% c(1955, 1956, 1970, 1971, 1995, 1996, 2011, 
             2012, 2020, 2021) ~ "Moderate La Nina", 
    y %in% c(1954, 1955, 1964, 1965, 1971, 1972, 1974, 
             1975, 1983, 1984, 1985, 2000, 2001, 2005, 
             2006, 2008, 2009, 2016, 2017, 2018) ~ "Weak La Nina", 
    TRUE ~ "No La Nina or El Nino events")
}  
AndreyIndex(5000)
# [1] "No La Nina or El Nino events"
```